# Getting from POST in included .html page in Django

Tags: python, django, include, http-post

I am trying to get the POST values of an .html page that has included pages via {% include %} in Django. However, it returns only the POST from the initial html page.

My inner html that is included has the snippet of code:

```
div id="edit_parameters"><a href="#{{job.slug}}" data-toggle="collapse">Edit Parameters</a></div>  
<div data-id="{{job.slug}}" id="{{job.slug}}" class="collapse">  
<form class = "form-inline" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for parameter in job.get_object.parameters %}
        <p>             
            <input type="text" class="input-small" name="{{parameter}}" value="" id ="{{parameter}}-input" placeholder="{{parameter}}">

        </p>
    {% endfor %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary run-job">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
{% else %}
<div>
No editable parameters for this job.
</div>
{% endif %}
```

And my outer HTML file has a snippet:

```
<ul id="available-jobs">
    {% if jobs_same_io_type and jobs_diff_io_type %}<h3> Current Step </h3>
    {% elif jobs_same_io_type %} <h3> Next Step </h3> {% endif %}
    {% for job in jobs_same_io_type %}
            {% include "includes/job_li.html" with add=1 %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if jobs_diff_io_type %} <h3> Next Step </h3> {% endif %}
    {% for job in jobs_diff_io_type %}
            {% include "includes/job_li.html" with add=1 %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if not jobs_same_io_type and not jobs_diff_io_type %}
    <li class="full-height">There are no more available jobs.</li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    <fieldset class="submit">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="job_to_run" value="" id="job-to-run" />
        <input type="hidden" name="workflow_jobs" value="" id="ordered-jobs" />
        <input type="hidden" name="job_to_edit" value="" id="job-to-edit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="job_to_add" value="" id="job-to-add" />
        <input type="hidden" name="job_to_remove" value="" id="job-to-remove" />
        <input type="submit" name="done" value="I'm done, start the jobs" id="jobs-ready" />
    </fieldset>
```

The everything that shows in post is in the inputs of the second snippet. But the parameters I want for the first snippet are not included when I use request.POST for all of the POST values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in explaining why I am not getting the values from the included page and finding a possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: HTTP allows for only one post. Looks you want to post several forms at once?

Comment: Is there a way to get the POST from a particular set of "parameters" or a particular form?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, only the fields in the form element that contain the submit button are included in the POST. the fields in your second file don't seem to be in any `form` at all, so they will never be posted.

Comment: The problem is that only the fields in the second file are showing up in post, not the things in the form in the first file though, this is strange.

Comment: I guess the form tags are in the bit of the HTML that you don't show. The point remains, though, that only the form containing the submit button you actually clicked gets submitted.

Comment: I thought so as well, however, it only submits the first iteration of the for loop now. So, only the first jobs parameters in addition to everything in the fieldset. That is, even if you click on submit for the second job, it still only submits the first parameters. I thought maybe this is because my forms were missing unique IDs but I added those and the problem persists.